# Deep Neural Network model starts learning with 80% accuracy, why?

Tags: machine-learning

My deep learning model e.g. conv1D, LSTM and conv2D all starts learning with 80% accuracy, what could be the reasons. ?

Comment: Possibly too loose fit tolerance (bias)

Comment: There can be many reasons. For example if the majority class is 80% of the data.